# Tasks Queue for Android - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, queue, task, runnable

I want to add Tasks (or Runnable) in queue that I want to execute in series.  New task comes in at run time, depending on conditions.
I also want to add a delay after each task before it starts the next one.

For example: I am downloading a file, and user taps another file to download. Now I dont want it to start in parallel. I want it to start only after first file is downloaded.

What would be the best way to do it in Kotlin for Android?

Comment: You can call `postDelayed` on any `View` to post a `Runnable` to the main message queue (or create a `Handler` using `Looper.getMainLooper()` and call `postDelayed` on that, if you don't have access to a view). Either make each runnable call `postDelayed` at the end of its code, and pass the next one in the queue, or make it call some central function that's handling the queue and posting each task when another one finishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does what you are asking for:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val delay = { millis:Long ->  Runnable { println("delay..."); Thread.sleep(millis) } }
    val r1 = Runnable { println("r1") }
    val r2 = Runnable { println("r2") }
    val r3 = Runnable { println("r3") }

    val queue: List<Runnable> = listOf(r1, delay(1_000), r2, delay(2_000), r3)
    
    thread {
        queue.forEach { it.run() }
    }

    // alternatively, if you have an ExecutorService:
    // 
    // executorService.execute { queue.forEach { it.run() } }
}
```

prints:

```
r1
delay...
r2
delay...
r3
```